# How do i get instance of a model with highest value from an operation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three models, directors, movies, and ratings. These are their relations: A **director** has_many **movies**, a **movie** belongs_to a **director**, a **movie** has_many **ratings** and a **rating** belongs_to a **movie**.

My schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2022_01_20_101906) do

  create_table "directors", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "first_name"
    t.date "date_of_birth"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "movies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.date "release_date"
    t.string "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "director_id"
    t.index ["director_id"], name: "index_movies_on_director_id"
  end

  create_table "ratings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "value"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "movie_id"
    t.index ["movie_id"], name: "index_ratings_on_movie_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at", precision: 6
    t.datetime "remember_created_at", precision: 6
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "movies", "directors"
  add_foreign_key "ratings", "movies"
end
```

I'm currently trying to display a director's best-rated movie to display on a _director.html.erb patrial, so I tried this code to get the highest-rated movie value:

```
<% array = [] %>
<% rat_val = 0 %>
<% result = 0 %>
<% director.movies.each do |movie| %>
   <% if movie.ratings.count > 0 %>
      <% director.movies.each do |movie| %>
         <% rat_val = number_with_precision(movie.ratings.average(:value), precision: 2) %>
         <% array << rat_val %>
         <% result = array.max %>
      <% end %>
        <%= result %>
      <% break %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But I'm struggling with what to do next to use this value to get the director's best-rated movie name to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work via this perhaps over-complicated loop:

```
  <% ratings_all = [] %>
  <% ratings_array = [] %>
  <% rating_avg = [] %>
  <% movies_rating = [] %>
  <% best_rating = 0 %>

  <% director.movies.each do |movie| %>

    <% if movie.ratings.count > 0 %>

      <% director.movies.each do |movie| %>

        <% ratings_all = movie.ratings.to_a %>
        <% ratings_array = ratings_all.map { |v| v[:value] } %>
        <% ratings_avg = (ratings_array.sum.to_f / ratings_array.count).round(2).to_f %>
        <% movies_rating << ratings_avg %>
        <% best_rating = movies_rating.max %>

      <% end %>

        <% if movie.ratings.average(:value).round(2) == best_rating %>
         <%= link_to movie.name, movie_path(movie) %>
         (<%= best_rating %>/5.0)

       <% end %>

    <% end %>

  <% end %>
```

but now it displays the name of the best rated movie on a directors and its rating, which is what I aimed to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

One way to obtain the best-rated movie from each director would be selecting the average rating values for each director movie, ordering by that calculation and limiting the rows returned to 1.

This would be very complex to achieve in ActiveRecord. Having the whole select statement to get the `movie_name` as a string, so here's just the SQL version:

```
SELECT
  d.*,
  (
    SELECT t.name
    FROM (
      SELECT name, (SELECT AVG(value) FROM ratings WHERE movie_id = movies.id) avgval
      FROM movies
      WHERE director_id = d.id
      ORDER BY avgval DESC
      LIMIT 1
    ) t
  ) movie_name
FROM directors d;
```

With this you don't need to manually iterate and counting raitings, you have every director column accessible plus the `movie_name`.

Comment: When i run it like this: `<% sql = "the SQL query above" %>
<% records_array = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(sql) %>
<%= records_array[0].entries[5][1] %>` 
I get the best rated movie for one director, but the other directors get the same movie as well, any idea what's causing that?

Comment: Can you share some of your records? Maybe I misunderstood something. Here's a working example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/75cb61

Comment: `Director.create(first_name: "Martin Scorsese", date_of_birth: "17/11/1942", id: 2)
Movie.create(name: "Skrytá identita", release_date: "06/10/2006", description:"description", director_id: 2)
Rating.create(value: 4, movie_id:1)
Rating.create(value: 3, movie_id:1)` these are some records from my seeds.rb @SebastianPalma. And first_name I actually use for the full name because I didn't want to edit column names/delete and make new.

Comment: I'm seeing only a single director. Could you take the records from the fiddle and see what you get? Or if you could share at least a gist with your seeds

Comment: I wrote only some of the records, the entire file wouldn't fit in here. How do I take the records from the fiddle? Sorry for my lack of knowledge, I'm still new to ruby on rails.

Comment: You can just copy and paste them from the insert statements. You'd need to somehow filter your query to use only those present there. Or as I mentioned, you could share your seeds file (gist, github or any other)

Comment: Oh I get it now, here's the [link](https://github.com/chleba381/rails-first-crud-web-app/blob/main/db/seeds.rb) then. The description is very long, that's why in the comment above I just rewrote it to"description"

Comment: Hey @chleba381 here's an overview and the results on my side https://gist.github.com/sebastian-palma/4ed0d4c942c30ba15dffb7ebc23ca322. As you can see it works as expected

Comment: It looks like an output from a console. When i tried this in the view, I just kept getting the wrong movie. I've solved it by finishing the code in the question. However I want to thank you for taking the time and patience with me. You are awesome!

Answer (score 1):

A better performing alternative to a subquery is to use a lateral join:

```sql
SELECT "directors".*, 
       "best_rated"."average_rating" AS rating 
FROM "directors" 
JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT AVG("ratings"."value") AS average_rating 
  FROM "movies" 
  INNER JOIN "ratings" ON "ratings"."movie_id" = "movies"."id" 
  WHERE "movies"."director_id" = "directors"."id" 
  GROUP BY "movies"."id" 
  ORDER BY "average_rating" DESC LIMIT 1
) best_rated ON true
```

This is somewhat like a foreach loop that selects a single row off the movies table which you can reference in the select clause. Writing the query with Arel/ActiveRecord is actually almost longer then the SQL string but is somewhat more portable.

```ruby
class Director < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :movies
  has_many :ratings, through: :movies

  # Select directors and the average ranking of their top ranking movie
  def self.with_top_rated_movie
    # this is the subquery for the lateral join
    lateral = Movie
                .select(
                  Rating.arel_table[:value].average.as('average_rating')
                  # You can add any additional columns you want from the movie here
                )
                .joins(:ratings)
                .group(:id)
                .order(average_rating: :desc)
                # WHERE movies.director_id = directors.id  This is our lateral reference
                .where(Movie.arel_table[:director_id].eq(arel_table[:id]))
                .limit(1)
    # This is the alias used by the lateral join
    best_rated = Movie.arel_table.alias('best_rated')
    select(
      arel_table[Arel.star],
      best_rated[:average_rating].as('rating')
      # You can add any additional columns you want from the movie here
    ).joins(
      "JOIN LATERAL (#{lateral.to_sql}) best_rated ON true"
    )
  end           
end
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the following would be clean, and sticks with using ActiveRecord:

```
director.movies.order(rating: :desc).first
```

Comment: You'd need to calculate `rating` in order to use it in the `order by`. Isn't a column on the movies table.

Comment: Oops, good call